# What could be causing my code to sporadically fail to get a connection to a SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql

I've been writing some test code for a program I'm developing.  Some of my code performs operations that modify data on a SQL Server.  In order to avoid cluttering my database with test data, I use transactions.  I run each test within a transaction and then roll back the transaction.

However, when I run my test code, it sporadically throws exception that it could not connnect to the SQL Server.  Even worse, it seems that sometimes, the transactions just float in the aether, locking tables in my database so that ordinary users cannot connect.  (This is a development environment database, but even still, it's a big hassle).

My tests are divided into about 100 tests; each test runs in it's own transaction; the tests run in sequence (or at least I think they should :-/).

If I run the tests one at a time, they always pass.  I only have trouble when running all 100 tests at once within Visual Studio 2008.  Each test runs very quickly, so I think that the problem has something to do with the SQL Server not being able to clean up the connection from a previous test and make available a new connection.

Is there some adjustment to my SQL Server configuration that may remedy this problem?

Comment: Could we please see your code? It may not be cleaning up correctly. (Did you post a question on SO about this same problem? If yes, please link to it.)

Comment: Yes, I did post a question of SO about this same problem.  I did post the code of SO since SO is a programming forum.  I felt  that I might get an answer from a different point of view here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072986/sql-server-and-transactionscope-with-msdtc-sporadically-cant-get-connection

Comment: The comment over in that question is a good one -- make sure your transactions are either committed or rolled back every time you create one. This can definitely cause problems with locking.

Comment: I've been looking over that.  In the case of test code, the transactions should always be rolled back and never committed, which I believe I'm doing correctly.  I think this may have something to do with the way the server makes connections available based on the fact that the test code runs fine whenever the tests are run one at a time, but sometimes fails when the tests are run all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are disposing of the connection object correctly after every call? It may be possible the connection pool is filling up and preventing further connections.

Comment: I thought I was disposing the connection properly because I used the `SqlHelper` class in my code.  However, it turns out that there was a `SqlDataReader` object in the code under test that wasn't closed properly.  Adding a single line of code to close the `SqlDataReader` fixed the problem; so it appears that there is nothing wrong with the server or its configuration; this problem was entirely programmatic in nature.